# How to setup Sikuli for selenium webdriver using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, sikuli

I'm using selenium webdriver with Ruby.  I want to practice with Sikuli. So does anyone know the way to install Sikuli, setup, and configure it for using Selenium with Ruby? Please show me step by step to do it?

---

I installed jruby and sikuli gem, and Sikuli IDE, but I donot know how to configure for them work together.

When I run script it always show that:

```
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sikuli-0.3.0/lib/sikuli/platform.rb:16:in `sikuli_script_path': Failed to load 'sikuli-script.jar' from the Sikuli home directory (LoadError)
Make sure %SIKULI_HOME% or $SIKULI_HOME is set!
from c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sikuli-0.3.0/lib/sikuli.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `require'
from c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `rescue in require'
from c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:35:in `require'
from C:/geoic/test_sikuli.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

Although I've already set SIKULI_HOME= C:\Program Files (x86)\Sikuli X\

Does anyone know the reason why? Please give me some idea.

Comment: If you detail what you've tried, you'll get better answers on SO.  For example, [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: Does anyone see this case? Please give me some idea.